# Servlet with jdbc response to client

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have a database with houses, and HTML page with `<SELECT>,` where user need to select a district where the houses are located.

Servlet:

```
   @WebServlet("/post")
   public class HosesBaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
          //choice from html form
        String choice = request.getParameter("district");

        //Database parameters
         final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb2";
         final String DB_USER = "root";
         final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
         Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connection available");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Square, RoomNumbers, Price FROM houses  WHERE  District = " + choice);

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Fail to connect with base");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I put SQL select results into HTML page  and give it back to client?

I created class House

```
public class Hosue implements Serializable {
    private String price;
    private String square;
    private String RoomNumbers;
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String getSquare() {
        return square;}
    public String getRoomNumbers() {
        return RoomNumbers;}

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setSquare(String square) {
        this.square = square;
    }

    public void setRoomNumbers(String roomNumbers) {
        RoomNumbers = roomNumbers;
    }
}
```

and houses

```
public class Houses {
public List<House> getList() {

}
}
```

and add script to my html. What next, how to add information from select to this list?

Comment: what technology are you preferring for front end jsp or pure html ?

Comment: Prefering pure html, because I don't quite understand how jsp works, when servlet send it to client, jsp translates to html? Maybe jsp will be better?

Comment: okay, wait i provide you solution. how to convert list of houses to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem as said by Jeed in the previous answer. However, it would be better if you model your db entities with Java objects and use them to encapsulate information from and towards the db. You may also use the DAO programming pattern to better organize your code, thus you can define simple objects (beans) to model data (your database entities) and data access object (DAO object) in which you would encode interaction with the db (your jdbc code).
Then you will have something like this to query your db (this code will be in your servlet):

```
HouseDAO h=new HouseDAO(db connection param...)
ArrayList<House> list=h.selectHouses();
```

In the HouseDAO object you will create a method selectHouse in which you will basically move the jdbc code you have in your servlet right now. By the way, your are missing a part in which you call the method execute query from the ps object. This method returns a ResultSet object which contains the query result.

With the code above, you will have your data in the ArrayList list, and you can use the code suggested by Jeed to output it.

Clearly, if you want to avoid using jsp, you can print your html code directly in your servlet. I do not recommend this as you would merge view details with control and model code. This is not good especially if you are planning to change your view in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add result of your query to some List or custom object and set it as attribute in your request object.

request.setAttribute("result", result);

and then forward to your next page using RequestDispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Gson external Library for sending java-List into String form to
>   HTML,

Your `Servlet` Code looks likewise,

```
List<House> listofHouses = getList from Database;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json_obj = gson.toJson(listofHouses);
response.getWriter().println(json_obj);
```

> Your HTML(use Jquery-ajax for Handling result & send Request to
>   Servlet ) Code looks some what nearer likewise......

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
            url: 'Servlet.do?distinct=YOUR_SELECTED_district_NAME',
            type: "POST/GET",
            data: query,
            dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
            var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);    
                alert(data);

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {

         ('#your_drop_down_tag_id').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', index));
            });

            }
        });

</script>
```

**NOTE: jquery-XXX.js file must be inclue into your project and into your html file properly.**

Comment: What is customObjResp?  and  where I should paste this Jquery script?

Comment: @Panwo kindly see update answer, and jquery script need to add into you r html page, at last of your body tag likewise, <body>...... <Script>..</script></body>.

Comment: ok, can you please explain more detail, i update question